# User parameters in Oracle Report Builder

Tags: sql, oracle, oraclereports

- What are the user parameters in Oracle Report Builder and what is the purpose of these parameters?
- What are the referencing columns and parameters, bind references, lexical references?
- What are the differences between bind and lexical references?

Comment: is this info not found in the manual?

Answer (score 0):

User parameters are user define parameters and they used to make your report dynamic. lexical reference which is also know as lexical parameters use in report triggers with the help of user parameters for example

`select * from emp where emp.smp_id`

above is your report query

and **param_emp_id**  and **param_where** are your user parameters  then in beforeparameter report trigger your simple lexical parameter should be

`if param_emp_id < 50 then
param_where := 'and emp.age > 30';
end if;`

and now your report query looks like following:

`select * from emp where emp.smp_id &param_where`

its mean the join of age is only works when emp id is less than 50 otherwise not, this is the simple example of lexical parameters or reference .

now what is bind reference which is also know as bind variables is directly used in your report query let say

`select * from emp where emp.emp_id < :param_emp_id`

above is the example of bind reference of our user parameter so simple is that if we use our user parameter directly in our report query its called bind reference.

Hope so its helpful for you !